# If I set bool_variable = not (3 * 2) != 4 + 2, what will be returned?

Tags: python

I'm kind of confused about this piece of code,

```
bool_variable = not (3 * 2) != 4 + 2.
```

If `not (3 * 2) == False`, then how can be a bool be compared to an int?

Comment: `bool` is a subset of `int`: `True == 1`, `False == 0`.

Comment: False is syntactic sugar for 0 and True is 0 so in this example you are comparing `0 != 6` which will result in False

Comment: @CasperKuethe It's not entirely true that it is syntactic sugar. Booleans have a semantics of their own, it only inherits the integer semantics for arithmetic.

Comment: In the end the interpreter will compare the numberical values, but yes Booleans do have some semantics e.g. print(True) will print True instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) table. `not` has lower precedence than `!=`, so this is treated as:

```
bool_variable = not ( (3 * 2) != (4 + 2) )
```

So the comparison is being done first, then its result is inverted by `not`.

Comment: According to this link, `not` has the same precedence as `!=`.

Comment: No it doesn't. You're misreading `not in`. `not` is the next line (it's written as `not x`) and described as `Boolean NOT`

Comment: Ah true, sorry.